# Tcl Regular Expression: Help Needed on non-greedy quantifiers in pattern with '(' , ')' characters

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a pattern like:  `substring1(substring2),(xxxx)xxxx`
Need `substring1` (string before first parenthesis) and `substring2` (string within first parenthesis) which is no problem.
Also, need all characters after the first parenthesis in one substring - these may be parenthesis themselves. 
Hence using the pattern - `regexp {(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*)} $a match sub1 sub2 sub3`
But the last substring cannot be collected in `sub3`.
Please help me!

```
> 247 % set a substring1(substring2),(xxxx)xxxx
> 248 % regexp {(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*)} $a match sub1 sub2 sub3 1
> 249 % puts $sub1; puts $sub2; puts $sub3 
substring1
substring2

> 250 %
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you've got is that Tcl's RE engine is automata-theoretic and doesn't cope very well with switching greediness modes. In particular, to a first approximation it is the case that the first quantifier in a string sets the greediness for the whole RE. (It's not actually true, but the rules for when it switches are highly arcane.)

If you don't have nested parentheses, you can just use this:

```
regexp {^([^()]*)\(([^()]*)\)(.*)$} $a match sub1 sub2 sub3
```

Testing (with obvious bits omitted):

```
% puts $sub1|$sub2|$sub3
substring1|substring2|,(xxxx)xxxx
```

---

Dealing with nested parentheses is far harder. The problem is that arbitrary nesting is where you cease to be dealing with a “language” which can be formally matched by a finite automaton (instead you need a pushdown automaton, which is a different decidability class). For a finite level of nesting, you can encode it; here's how to do it with one level:

```
regexp {^([^(]*)\(((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*)\)(.*)$} $a match sub1 sub2 sub3
```

That is, I replaced `[^()]` with `(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))`. You can easily go deeper by replacing the second sub-`[^()]` by that again, as much as you want. However, this makes the RE more complex (which is actually the problem; an arbitrary nested paren matcher would require an infinitely long RE). If you're dealing with that particular problem, it's easier to try to find some other technique (e.g., a longer “end of chunk” string to match like `),` — with the comma — or using a recursive parser).

Answer (score 1):

Need to terminate with match till end variable **'$'**

```
 () 27 % regexp {(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*).*$} $a match sub1 sub2 sub3
 1
 () 28 % set sub3
 ,(xxxx)xxxx
 () 29 % set sub1
 substring1
 () 30 % set sub2
 substring2
 () 31 % set sub3
 ,(xxxx)xxxx
```

Comment: +1 good idea. In my problem `$` was inappropriate, but this answer 
inspired me to use `<tag>.*?</tag>\s*(?=\S)` to fix the non-working
`<tag>.*?</tag>\s*` when I wanted to include all trailing white-spaces in the match.